# Download table from wunderground with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I would like to Weather History & Observations table from the following link:

https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/HDY/2011/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2011&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

 link = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/HDY/2011/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2011&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo='

 resp = requests.get(link)

 c = resp.text

 soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
```

I would like to know what is the next step to access the table info at the bottom of the page (assuming this is a good website format to allow this to happen).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all`

```
table = soup.find('table', class_="responsive obs-table daily")
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how to put the rows and column headers into a dataframe? I should have added that as a requirement. Apologies